# How can i build a processing engine

Tags: php, html

So i built a php system that consists of 2 pages. The functions of these are:

Page 1: Basic form, for input data, POST to page 2.

Page 2: Load input data from page 1, process everything and make appropriate calculations, then take the resulting data and use it to determine file names o overlay on a master template.

It works fine, I just wanted to know if it's possible to add a "middleman" in between the 2 pages, an engine if you will, that processes everything, instead of page 2 having to do it, then it will automatically POST to page 2 upon completion where it will load the results and use them, however, if  there is an error, it will reload page 1. I just want to try and keep things more organised and neat.

Thanks guys

Comment: A middleman could be really annoying to users. Handle the “redirection” server-side. Or is your question how to build/use a template engine?

Comment: Nah man, the redirection will be client side, but the page wont even be there for that long, probably like a split second, considering It only has to work through about 200 lines of logic script to determine the outcome of a few things

Comment: @amartin94 as soon as you start transferring data between the client and the server, you'll have _no_ idea how long could that take

Comment: The split second is enough to both break the page for anyone without JavaScript (considering you said POST) and the back button, too. Please don't do it ^_^

Comment: Actually, now i think of it, i guess i could just use require() and call the external engine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally a good idea to split your "business logic" from the "application logic" and "presentation layer" - though on a 2-page app, that may not be such a priority.

There are many designs for accomplishing this; the most commonly accepted is "Model/View/Controller". There are a bunch of PHP frameworks which implement MVC in PHP; again, possibly overkill for a 2 page app, but worth investigating if you expect to grow much beyond 2 pages.

The way to solve your specific question:

- Page 1 posts to formhandler.php.
- Formhandler.php validates data, and executes business logic.
  If data is valid, formhandler puts data into session and uses `header` function to redirect browser to page 2; page 2 gets data from header and displays
- If data is not valid, formhalder puts error message and data into session, and uses `header` to redirect back to page 1.

Formhandler.php should have no HTML embedded in it - it just executes the business logic. Pages 1 and 2 should have no business logic, but may have some application logic (to show the error messages on page 1, for instance).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`header`](http://php.net/header) in the "middle man" script - but it won't work if you already made some outputs with print/echo in the "middle man" script:

```
header("Location: middlemanscript.php?".$yourVars);
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought about header, but didnt know you could pass variables through aswell :)

And no, the middleman/engine is just used to run a logic system i wrote to determine the outcome of a few things to pass through to the second page, no printing necessary :)

Comment: Since the parameter of the header-method is a string you can build it up like this - but I don't know if there are any "don't"s with this.